# Animating Placeholder Text?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, animation, placeholder

Can anybody help me with adding my text animation into a form I have created?

The text currently animates when you refresh the page, this works fine although I need it working like a placeholder in the form.

Once a user clicks on the form the text needs to disappear enabling the user to be able to search normally.

Please see my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdpK5/)

If anybody could assist please update the fiddle, your help is much appreciated !

```
var txt = $('.writer').text();
var timeOut;
var txtLen = txt.length;
var char = 0;
$('.writer').text('|');
(function typeIt() {   
    var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (200 - 30)) + 30;
    timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        char++;
        var type = txt.substring(0, char);
        $('.writer').text(type + '|');
        typeIt();

        if (char == txtLen) {
            $('.writer').text($('.writer').text().slice(0, -1)); // remove the '|'
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }

    }, humanize);
}());
```

Comment: you mean the placeholder text shall be animated? and removed once the user clicks?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/FaLs4/)

Basically, include the custom text in the `'var txt'` rather than looking up the DOM to get the text.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for attr('placeholder') ?

```
$('.main-search').attr('placeholder');
```

see my update: http://jsfiddle.net/tdpK5/1/

Comment: Thanks for this. How can I remove the other text that isnt in the placeholder. I removed it and it breaks.